# IOS-Fixed content in UIScrollview

Tags: ios, uiscrollview, uilabel

I have a problem with `UIScrollView` and `UILabel`. I'm adding `UILabel` using `addSubview` inside `UIScrollView`, one `UILabel` on the top

set Width: 3000 - height: 20;

other `UILabel` on the left: set height: 1000 - width: 50;

In the middle `UISCrollView` is [here](http://mocku.ps/20zxhb)

I wanna

- When scroll horizontal the `UILabel` on the top move to left or right (doesn't move to up or down)
- When scroll vertical the `UILabel` on the left move to up or down (doesn't move right or left)

Comment: So basically you want that when the user drags the view in one direction, it moves in another? That's something an UX deisgner would kill you for. Twice.

Comment: you check my code - http://www.mediafire.com/download.php?rawba5ronh9zers